# What is the simplest way to play a 1-second sound in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

What is the easiest library / framework to use?
I see lots of libraries but don't know which the industry standard is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working Code for you to make it simpler. This works perfectly in my game.

```
import AVFoundation

var bgMusic:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

var bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("yourTune", withExtension: "mp3")!
bgMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error: nil)
bgMusic.numberOfLoops = 1
bgMusic.prepareToPlay()
bgMusic.play()

}
```

> Make sure to change the name of your tune! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional library to play sounds in iOS. Just use what is provided to you by the corresponding SDK: [`AVAudioPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/).